# Hibernate returns a wrong Entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jta

here the scenario:

my first method executes a hibernate query on a entity SContact.class.

Withing the first method a second method is called to query on SContactX.class.

Whenever the second query is fired hibernate throws the following exception:

***javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=1-1A5V6Z] was not of the specified subclass [com.qvc.crm.esp.entity.siebel.SContactX] : loaded object was of wrong class class com.qvc.crm.esp.entity.siebel.SContact***

Here the first method:

```
 @Override
    @Transactional(value = "transactionManagerAftReplicDb", readOnly = true)
    public List<SContact> identifyCustomers(CompanyCode companyCode, CustomerSearchSpec customerSearchSpec) throws ApplicationException {
            List<SContact> resultList = null;
        QueryBuilder criteria = new QueryBuilder(SContact.class).equals(customerSearchSpec.getSearchFieldName(), customerSearchSpec.getSearchFieldValue())
                .equals("buId", resultListBu.get(0).getRowId());
        QueryConfig queryConfig = new QueryConfig(criteria, getEntityManager());
        queryConfig.withEnd(customerSearchSpec.getCustomerLimit().intValue());
        resultList = queryConfig.query(SContact.class); // executes a query agains SContact
        map(resultList); // executes a query agains SContactX
        return resultList;
    }



 @Override
    public List<Customer> map(List<SContact> contacts) {
        List<Customer> foundCustomer = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(contacts)) {
            for (SContact contact : contacts) {
                SContactX contactExt = loadContextExt(contact);
                ...
            }
        }
        return foundCustomer;
    }

  @Transactional(value = "transactionManagerAftReplicDb", readOnly = true)
    private SContactX loadContextExt(SContact contact) {
        TypedQuery<SContactX> query = getEntityManager().createQuery("FROM SContactX where rowId = :rowId", SContactX.class);
        query.setParameter("rowId", contact.getRowId());
        SContactX result = query.getSingleResult(); // thows exception!
        return result;
    }
```

SCONTACT:

```
  @Entity
@Table(name = "S_CONTACT")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SContact extends SiebelBaseEntity {
```

SCONTACTX:

```
  @SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "S_CONTACT_X")
public class SContactX extends SiebelBaseEntity {
```

SIEBELBASEENTITY:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public abstract class SiebelBaseEntity extends BaseEntity {
```

BASEENTITY.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
```

Comment: Please, provide your ScontactX and SContact classes.

Comment: Jep just did it. See my code above

Comment: Post **all** the relevant code. Other questions on this issue discuss inheritance. What is SiebelBaseEntity? What other mappings may be relevant?

Comment: Post the code of SiebelBaseEntity. My guess is that it's annotated with Entity, and shouldn't be.

Comment: What was the SQL invoked to retrieve an object? You seem to have forgotten "SELECT {alias}" from your JPQL ...

Comment: I now added also the parent classes. See code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue by changing the annotation of the super class SiebelBaseEntity to:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public abstract class SiebelBaseEntity extends BaseEntity {
```